# Hole filling of color pictures

Tags: image, imagemagick, gimp, image-editing

I would like to perform some image editing by removing annoying element on these image such as electric poles, grids, ... (pic. 1)

The amount of edits to perform is quite significant and I wonder if it is possible to automatize the refilling (pic. 3) process after deleting the annoying parts with GIMP (pic. 2).

[image]
[image]
[image]

**What are the possibilities (scripts, processes, extensions modules, softwares, ...) to automatize the refilling process from picture 2 to picture 3 ? Preferably with GIMP, imagemagick, or any open source softwares ?**

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way in Gimp is to use the [resynthesizer plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/27986). I don't know how up-to-date the code on the Gimp reigsitry is but AFAIK it is bundled in the Windows and OSX Gimp builds from [partha.com](http://www.partha.com/), and is in the repository of some Linux distros.